# SSO Issue With ZK Framework?

Tags: windows, single-sign-on, zk

I am using SSO login for my web-application.My code is as given below:

```
@Command("doSSOLogin")
@NotifyChange("showConflictWindow")
public void doSSOLogin(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
logger.info("Login Button is clicked..");
doSSOLoginAuthorization(LoginType.LOGIN_IF_NO_CONFLICT);

}

private void doSSOLoginAuthorization(LoginType argLoginType) {
HttpServletResponse response = getHttpServletResponse();
HttpServletRequest request = getHttpServletRequest();

if (selectedDatabase == null) {
Messagebox.show("Must select a database", "Error", Messagebox.OK,
Messagebox.ERROR);
return;
}
String Authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
if (Authorization == null) {
logger.info("Authoriztion is null");
response.reset();
response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NEGOTIATE");
response.setContentLength(0);
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
response.setHeader("connectionCache", selectedDatabase.getValue());
response.setHeader("languageType", selectedLanguage.getValue());
try {
response.flushBuffer();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return;
} else {
String token = Authorization.substring("NEGOTIATE ".length());
logger.info("Authoriztion is not null having token ::" + token);
if (token.startsWith("TlRM")) {
logger.debug("We do not support NTLM authentication: " + token);
System.out.println("We do not support NTLM authentication");
return;
}
}
}
```

When a user clicks on login button it goes through this code & first time Authorization is null.So set authorization in request header and asks for window credentials  & second time when I click on this button again,I get Authorization.
But I dont want to click button again and this work should be done on single click as it is already work in my previous application but technology was jsp.

Is it issue of using ZK or something else in my code?
If you have any solution to call back ,please help me out.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put Your if statement code in doAfterCompose() Method. And put else code in a seprate method which will be called when user will click on the button.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for Reply!It is working for me but I need exact solution not  so-so solution